# Where can I see the reason why an example in Documentation got deleted?

Tags: support, documentation

Where can I see the reason why an example in Documentation got deleted?

E.g. this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join/14930/differences-between-sql-joins#t=201608260634345) was deleted, where can I see the reason why it was  removed?

Comment: If you go back to the edit history, it looks like multiple people complained about the quality of that example and it was removed as a result: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/89434

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The interface for Documentation is anything but intuitive, and pages are so busy that relevant links are easily lost. Here are the steps:

1. Click on "view prior to deletion".
2. When the [original topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/261/join/14930/differences-between-sql-joins#t=201608260634345) appears, open its edit history. You can do this by clicking the "edited x hours ago" link at the bottom-right corner.
3. On the [edit history page](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sql/revisions/261?exampleId=14930), you'll see all of the edits listed in reverse chronological order. The deletion is going to be the last edit, of course, and it even says "deleted an example" as the summary. Click on the "View Edit" button to the right.
4. That'll show you [the changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/89434) responsible for deleting the topic. As with all changesets, in the right-hand margin, there's a box that contains vital stats: the person who submitted the edit, the explanatory comment that they left, and the other users who approved (or rejected) the edit.

   In this case, the comment isn't especially enlightening. It just says "Handling improvement requests". To understand what that means, you'll need to click the drop-down arrow for the orange improvement requests banner. They say:

   > This example is completely unclear, incomplete, or has severe formatting problems. It is unlikely to be salvageable through editing and should be removed.
   >
   > - Venn Diagrams are for 2-state boolean algebra. SQL has 3-state booleans. Also, Venn-diagrams are a poor visualization for SQL-joins, and do more damage than they do good. - Stefan Steiger
   >
   > This example does not sufficiently illustrate the point and needs to be edited to provide more details.
   >
   > - I am missing the join type CROSS JOIN. - Olivier Jacot-Descombes

Comment: Thanks, I guess there is no way to distinguish  improvement requests from deletion reasons?

Comment: The idea is, the person who "handled" the "improvement request" (in this case, John Odom), thought the best way to handle it was to delete the topic. Two reviewers apparently agreed with him.

Comment: And one of the reviewers left a comment on the example. (Approval votes cannot have a remark.)

Comment: Maybe these things should be documented...oh wait.